# Trying to install mysql2 gem, CertificateFailureError during bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

```
Jason-Kim-MacBook-Pro:composer jkim$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Resolving dependencies...

Bundler::Fetcher::CertificateFailureError: Could not verify the SSL certificate for https://rubygems.org/.
There is a chance you are experiencing a man-in-the-middle attack, but most likely your system doesn't have the CA certificates needed for verification. For information about OpenSSL certificates, see bit.ly/ssl-certs. To connect without using SSL, edit your Gemfile sources and change 'https' to 'http'.
An error occurred while installing rake (10.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

My gemfile includes `gem "mysql2"`.

I am OS X Lion, and using Ruby 1.8.7. Rails is 3.2.12.

I installed rake btw.

```
Jason-Kim-MacBook-Pro:composer jkim$ gem install rake -v '10.0.3'
Successfully installed rake-10.0.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rake-10.0.3...
Installing RDoc documentation for rake-10.0.3...
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I ran into this exact error. Simply rerunning the command fixed it for me. No editing of the gemfile required. https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/6.1-to-6.2.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still don't know exactly what the problem was, but I fixed it by not using https.

In your gemfile, change the source to `source 'http://rubygems.org'`